# Why are the results of NetQuantPD Ang Rnc and NetQuantPD Ang R50c identical after integrated analysis in SDNA？

Tags: arcgis-10.0, sdna

In the integration analysis of SDNA, the radii values are n and 50, but the NetQuantPD Ang Rnc and NetQuantPD Ang R50c values in the results are exactly the same.

Is the reason for this because the research area is too small?

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly imply, if results are the same this implies your whole area fits within a network distance of 50 of ... whatever spatial unit your data is using

(assuming a euclidean radius)

(and also assuming continuous space analysis, which you are using as shown by the 'c' after 50. In discrete space, it would imply all link *centroids* were within that distance, but the situation is similar).

Your area may indeed be really small, but a second possibility is you are not using the units you expect e.g. you might expect 50 metres, but if your data is in WGS84 GCS then 50 degrees would cover a good chunk of the world. To fix that, reproject to suitable local coordinates such as a national grid, or one of the *local* projections of WGS84.

In discrete space, a third possibility would be
that the network data has the wrong connectivity rules, so you'd see only results for each link considered in isolation. Check for isolated systems using sDNA Prepare to be sure. Given you're using continuous space this isn't the cause here, though it's always worth checking this anyway.